# Empaquetamiento en java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un proyecto para mi universidad y tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

1. La universidad me exige que haga el empaquetamiento de mi programa pero al hacerlo pasa esto, no muestra ningun tipo de imagen, estoy utilizando la siguiente funcion que es:

   ```
   ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon("src/imagenes/descarga.png");
   Icon icono = new ImageIcon(imagen.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblfondo.getWidth(), lblfondo.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
   lblfondo.setIcon(icono);
   ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber si alguno de ustedes me podria dar una solucion a este problema, gracias.

el programa al ejecutarlo en java sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: nada, no funciono, basicamente utilizo el  imaganeIcon para ajustar la imagen en un Jlabel

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el último código que has intentado? El código que hay en esta pregunta desde luego no te va a funcionar, por lo explicado en la pregunta asociada. Así que se trataría de corregir esta última versión. También comprueba que en el .jar esté el fichero de la imagen, y en qué ruta está.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con @SJuan76, la solución a tu problema se encuentra en el enlace compartido, ahora claro está tendrás que tener en cuenta que tu caso tienes unas rutas diferentes por lo cual al invocar la función getResource tendrías que pasar la cadena **"/imagenes/descarga.png"**

Comment: muchachos, muchas gracias en verdad ya funciono :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/src/imagenes/descarga.png"));
```